# Delphi XE5 Exception class $C00000005 when calling external function from own class

Tags: delphi, dll

The Exception only  ocures when I'm calling the external function from my class:

```
unit main;

interface

  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

function AmApiInit(bStartAmIfNotRunning: Boolean; dwTimeout: LongWord; pbProcessCreated: PBoolean): Boolean; stdcall; external 'C:\Users\Vexatus\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects\automapa\tpcAmApi.dll' name '?AmApiInit@@YA_N_NKPA_N@Z';

type
    TAutoMapa = class(TObject)
      function Start: Boolean;
    end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  AutoMapa: TAutoMapa;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TAutoMapa.Start: Boolean;

  begin

    Result := AmApiInit(True, 10000, nil);

  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin

  Edit1.Text := BoolToStr(AutoMapa.Start);

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  AutoMapa := TAutoMapa.Create;

end;

end.
```

So the problematic part is:

```
Edit1.Text:=BoolToStr(AutoMapa.Start);
```

If I call the external function directly it does work fine:

```
Edit1.Text:=BoolToStr(AmApiInit(True,10000,nil));
```

Here's the VC++ definition of the external function:

```
AMAPI bool AmApiInit(bool bStartAmIfNotRunning, DWORD dwTimeout, bool* pbProcessCreated);
```

I'm googling for the solution for the 3 days now so any help will be aprpiciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that AutoMapa object is nil, are you sure that you are creating it? Maybe your FormCreate event is not properly connected with Form

Comment: @Dalija Since the method doesn't use Self and is neither virtual nor dynamic, you can call it on a nil ref. Just like Free. So that's not it. The calling convention mismatch would present a problem though.

Comment: @David True, but it would not be the first time we don't have full code, that method could have more code that is not presented here. I guess you were on the right track here.

Comment: @Dalija, I also don't have the code of the dll and. I've read that parameter type mismatch can cause this issue. However, my VC++ knowladge was insuffitient to notice that.

Comment: I meant your code in Start function. You could have code in there you thought it is not relevant to the question, and that code could throw AV if you accessed Self at any point. I didn't have time to thoroughly look at code you have posted, and I noticed your statement that function works if you call it directly and it does not if you call it through AutoMapa object hence my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function name [demangles](http://demangler.com/) to:

```
BOOL __cdecl AmApiInit(BOOL,unsigned long,BOOL *)
```

Note that the `BOOL` type is a 4 byte type. It's `LongBool` in Delphi. And note the calling convention.

So the function should be declared like this:

```
function AmApiInit(bStartAmIfNotRunning: LongBool; dwTimeout: LongWord; 
  pbProcessCreated: PLongBool): LongBool; 
  cdecl; external '...' name '?AmApiInit@@YA_N_NKPA_N@Z';
```

---

Quite possibly the function doesn't allow you to pass `nil` for the final parameter. In which case declare a `LongBool` local variable and pass its address. Or declare the function like this:

```
function AmApiInit(bStartAmIfNotRunning: LongBool; dwTimeout: LongWord; 
  out pbProcessCreated: LongBool): LongBool; 
  cdecl; external '...' name '?AmApiInit@@YA_N_NKPA_N@Z';
```

However, if you succeeded with a call passing `nil` there then this second part of the answer is probably not pertinent.

Comment: Changing the convention (to the proper one) and Boolean into LongBool solved the issue. Thanks a lot David!

Comment: There is a `BOOL` type (defined as an alias for `LongBool`) in the `Windows` unit.